# iAd covers app content in phonegap?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, iad

I have this in my `webViewDidFinishLoad`:

```
- (void)setupAdBanner {
    adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    CGRect adFrame = adView.frame;
    if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
       || [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier =
        ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
        adFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height-adView.frame.size.height;
    } else {
        adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier =
        ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
        adFrame.size.width = adView.frame.size.width;
        adFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height-adView.frame.size.height;
    }
    adView.frame = adFrame;

    [self.view addSubview:adView];
}
```

This overlaps HTML content in my phonegap application. How do I adjust my webview frame sizes to account for the ad banner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact problem. I blogged about my solution here http://hawkinbj.wordpress.com/2013/04/16/implement-iad-banner-ads-without-covering-uiwebview-in-phonegap/

You need to implement ADBannerViewDelegateProtocolReference. In MainViewController.h:

```
@interface MainViewController : CDVViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate> 
{
    ADBannerView *adView;
}
@end
```

The rest of the steps are in MainViewController.m.

In webViewDidFinishLoad:

```
adView.delegate = self;
```

Add these two methods:

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner 
{
    CGRect resizedWebView = [super webView].frame;
    resizedWebView.size.height = adView.frame.origin.y;
    [super webView].frame = resizedWebView;
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:adView];
    adView.hidden = NO;
} 

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    CGRect resizedWebView = [super webView].frame;
    resizedWebView.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height;
    [super webView].frame = resizedWebView;
    adView.hidden = YES;
}
```

The magic is 
    `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:adView];`